# Firebase Rules: Needed some assistance

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, web-development-server

I'm working on a project where I'm having difficulty setting up permissions for moderators. Despite adding a helper function to check if a user is a moderator, it appears that my implementation is not functioning as expected. I've added console logs and it seems like the error is occurring at getModeratorSnippets.

Here's an overview of my code:

```
const onAddRemoveModerator = async (
    user: User,
    communityData: Community,
    isModerator?: boolean
  ) => {
    try {
      setLoadingModeratorMap((prevLoadingMap) => ({
        ...prevLoadingMap,
        [user.uid]: true, // Set loading state to true for the specific user
      }));

      if (!isModerator) {
        // Change the condition here
        // User is not a moderator, add them
        const newSnippet: ModeratorSnippet = {
          communityId: communityData.id,
          isModerator: true,
          userUid: user.uid,
        };

        const batch = writeBatch(firestore);
        batch.set(
          doc(
            firestore,
            `users/${user?.uid}/moderatorSnippets`,
            communityData.id
          ),
          newSnippet
        );
        await batch.commit();

        setCommunityStateValue((prev) => ({
          ...prev,
          moderatorSnippets: [...prev.moderatorSnippets, newSnippet],
        }));

        setIsModerator(true);
      } else {
        // User is already a moderator, remove them
        const batch = writeBatch(firestore);
        batch.delete(
          doc(
            firestore,
            `users/${user?.uid}/moderatorSnippets/${communityData.id}`
          )
        );
        await batch.commit();

        setCommunityStateValue((prev) => ({
          ...prev,
          moderatorSnippets: prev.moderatorSnippets.filter(
            (snippet) =>
              snippet.communityId !== communityData.id ||
              snippet.userUid !== user.uid
          ),
        }));

        setIsModerator(false);
      }

      setLoadingModeratorMap((prevLoadingMap) => ({
        ...prevLoadingMap,
        [user.uid]: false, // Set loading state to false for the specific user
      }));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("handleAddRemoveModerator error", error);
    }
  };


const fetchModeratorList = async () => {
    setLoadMoreLoading(true);
    const list: User[] = [];
    try {
      let querySnapshot;
      if (searchQuery) {
        const startAtKeyword = searchQuery.toUpperCase();
        const endAtKeyword = searchQuery.toLowerCase() + "\uf8ff";

        const queryRef = query(
          collection(firestore, "users"),
          orderBy("displayName"),
          startAt(startAtKeyword),
          endAt(endAtKeyword)
        );
        querySnapshot = await getDocs(queryRef);
      } else {
        querySnapshot = await getDocs(query(collection(firestore, "users")));
      }

      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        list.push(doc.data() as User);
      });
      setModeratorList(list);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log("error", error);
    }
    setSearchLoading(false);
    setLoadMoreLoading(false);
  };

const getSnippets = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const snippets = await getMySnippets(user?.uid!);
      setCommunityStateValue((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        mySnippets: snippets as CommunitySnippet[],
        initSnippetsFetched: true,
      }));
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log("Error getting user snippets", error);
      setError(error.message);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };

const getModeratorSnippets = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const snippets = await getAllModeratorSnippets();
      setCommunityStateValue((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        moderatorSnippets: [...snippets], // Replace the existing snippets with the new ones
        initSnippetsFetched: true,
      }));
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log("Error getting snippets", error);
      setError(error.message);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

const getAllModeratorSnippets = async () => {
    const snippetsCollection = collectionGroup(firestore, "moderatorSnippets");
    const snippetsDocs = await getDocs(snippetsCollection);
    const snippets: ModeratorSnippet[] = [];

    snippetsDocs.forEach((doc) => {
      const snippet = doc.data() as ModeratorSnippet;

      if (snippet.isModerator === true) {
        snippets.push({ ...snippet });
      }
    });

    return snippets;
  };
```

Here's my rules:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
    // Allow users to read, write, get, and update their own data
    match /users/{userId}/{restOfPath=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
      
      // Allow moderators to read, write, update, and get
      match /moderatorSnippets/{communityId} {
        allow read, write: if isModerator(userId, communityId);
      }
      
    }
  
  // Helper function to check if the user is a moderator
  function isModerator(userId, communityId) {
    return request.auth != null &&
           exists(/databases/(database)/documents/users/$(userId)/moderatorSnippets/$(communityId));
  }
  
}
```

I've attempted to implement a helper function (isModerator) to check if the user is a moderator before granting read and write permissions for moderatorSnippets. However, it doesn't seem to be working as expected.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it in the firebase console?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have missed an important section in the Firebase documentation, which explains that [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters). The rules don't filter data on their own, but rather only ensure that your code only requests data that it has access to.

Since your code requests all documents from `moderatorSnippets` and you've set up your rules to disallow that, the rules engine rejects that read operation.

---

The correct set up is to ensure that your code only requests documents that are allowed according to your rules. So you must write your query to match the rules.

I'm not sure if that's possible with your current data model though, as a query can only filter/order on information that is present in the documents that it returns and your rules seem to check the existence of another document (`exists(/databases/(database)/documents/users/$(userId)/moderatorSnippets/$(communityId))`).

If this is indeed a separate document, you will need to duplicate the information in the `moderatorSnippets` that you're querying, so that you can filter on it there - and then secure *that* through your rules.